# Overlay label background with buttons in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have the following elements on my borderpane, but i would like the white background to go behind the buttons.  How can i do this?

I have this

[image]

But would like something like this

[image]

In order to set this up, i am using fxml. See below

```
<VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
     <children>
        <Label styleClass="text-tab" text="Local Offers" />
        <Label styleClass="text-tab-sub" text="My text label with white bg" />
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-shopping" />
                 </styleClass>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-eat" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="120.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-leisure" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="230.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-home" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="330.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-health" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="430.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-services" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
              <Button layoutX="560.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Button">
                 <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="btn-category" />
                    <String fx:value="btn-events" />
                 </styleClass>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </Button>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

Here is css that i have applied so far (minus css to color each button).

```
.text-tab {
    -fx-font-size: 39;
    -fx-background-color: #FFC000;
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 5 10 0 10;
}

.text-tab-sub {
    -fx-font-size: 30;
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: #3B5999;
}

.btn-category {
    -fx-border-color:#ffffff;
    -fx-border-radius:15;
    -fx-border-width:4;
    -fx-background-radius:20;
    -fx-margin: 10 10 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some example code for us to work with?

Comment: Sorry, added fxml and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires an additional style-class and another CSS rule:

```
.white-half {
  -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 50%, white, white 49%, white 99%, transparent);
}
```

This CSS rule paints its upper half with a white background and its lower half with a transparent background.

Now you need to assign this style class to the `HBox` containing the `Button`s:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="white-half">
```

Next you want to strech the `Label` with the white background to the whole width:

```
<Label styleClass="text-tab-sub" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="My text label with white bg" />
```

This is done by setting its `maxWidth` property to `Double.MAX_VALUE`.